# How to generate random token?

Tags: custom-component, joomla-3.5

I am trying to generate a token using [JCryptCipherCrypto](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JCryptCipherCrypto.html) and I wanted to generate a string which will contain a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and length must be of 16 characters.

I have done this:

```
$crypto = new JCryptCipherCrypto;
$key = $crypto->generateKey();
```

Its method is not working or maybe I am doing something wrong :(

Can anyone tell me a better way to generate a token string or explain to me what I am missing?

Comment: Your server is probably missing `mcrypt` extension. Install / allow it and everything should work. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479983/cant-find-mcrypt-call-to-undefined-function-laravel-mcrypt-create-iv) for more information.

Comment: I have mycrypt extension enabled but still it is giving me result like this - VVz�E�$%����]6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For generating tokens I have used this method

```
function generateToken($length)
{
    jimport('joomla.user.helper');
    $token = JUserHelper::genRandomPassword($length);

    return $token;
}
```

Main advantage of this method is that I can generate random string up to 32 char.

Answer (score 1):

This result is exactly what you want. Now you have a key to encrypt data. And later you can decrypt it with the same key.

```
// Test string
$str = 'Lorem ipsum...';

// Get key
$crypto = new JCryptCipherCrypto;
$key = $crypto->generateKey();

// Crypt it. Nobody can read it without key
$crypted = $crypto->encrypt($str, $key);

// Decrypt crypted string
$decrypted = $crypto->decrypt($crypted, $key);
echo $decrypted;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Lorem ipsum...
```